# GeoJSON not visible in output rendered by code using D3.js v3

Tags: d3.js, maps

I'd like to visualize a geojson file in the EPSG:4326 coordinate reference system using D3.js version 3. I'm aware it's better to use the newest version, but alas I'm restricted because of old software that doesn't support higher versions.

I wrote this code: https://bl.ocks.org/FrieseWoudloper/141945ce346639013ac1ced8e4c071b7

In the resulting output there is an SVG element with paths, but I don't see it. I think I have the translate and scale arguments wrong, but I don't know how to determine the right values. Could you please give me any directions on how to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you give the SVG width and height attributes?

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/12s3pm5L/1/

Comment: Yes, now I can see the rendered output! Thank you very much! Is there a way to calculate the optimal value for the scale attribute? The paths are so small now.

Comment: You can try getting the bounding box for the paths then zoom or update the scale to the bounding box.